# Filter values out of a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, filter, threshold

I am almost sure there has to be a MATLAB way for this, but I don't have much experience:

```
width=length(hsvSecond(:,1,1));
height=length(hsvSecond(1,:,1));
for i=1:width
    for j=1:height
        if(hsvSecond(i,j,2)>0.35)
            hsvSecond(i,j,1)=0;
            hsvSecond(i,j,2)=0;
            hsvSecond(i,j,3)=0;
        end    
    end
end
```

So, basically, if the `hsvSecond(i,j,2)` value is bigger than a number, I want to put `hsvSecond(i,j,:)` to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple one-liner:

```
hsvSecond(repmat(hsvSecond(:,:,2) > 0.35, [1,1,3])) = 0;
```

or this possibly more efficient alternative (although some rudimentary test suggest otherwise which does surprise me):

```
hsvSecond = bsxfun(@times, hsvSecond(:,:,2) <= 0.35, hsvSecond)
```

---

Some comments on your code though:

```
width=length(hsvSecond(:,1,1));
height=length(hsvSecond(1,:,1));
```

Should be

```
width = size(hsvSecond,1)
height = size(hsvSecond,2)
```

and

```
hsvSecond(i,j,1)=0;
hsvSecond(i,j,2)=0;
hsvSecond(i,j,3)=0;
```

could have been

```
hsvSecond(i,j,:)=0;
```